# How to setup reminder in Microsoft Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams, reminders

I am using Microsoft Teams on Windows O.S and using Agile practices for Project.

I want to set up a reminder in teams so that my team (10 to 15 team members) will update their update on a daily basis. It will save our time.

I checked some tools/bots for teams, but those are paid, trying to configure 'Power apps' not sure how to configure it.

Update :

- We are taking scrum on daily basis and its taking too much time (15 members ,each member is taking approx. 5 min time)
- Instead of that want to set up a reminder at a particular time, so that each team member will post his 'plan for the day' on teams channel, it will save our time.
- Looking free tools for this activity ,since our company is a small size company.

Comment: Hi @Sunil, you can try having proactive messaging in that case. Can you please elaborate what features you are looking for?

Comment: Any update @Sunil?

Comment: @Saonti-MSFT : Added my update in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Enhancement**

Following the [Scrum Guide](https://scrumguides.org/docs/scrumguide/v2020/2020-Scrum-Guide-US.pdf#zoom=100) in Scrum Team Accountability size rule section,

> The Scrum Team is small enough to remain nimble and large enough to
> complete significant work within a Sprint, typically 10 or fewer
> people....

you should split your scrum team, (e.g 7 / 8). This mean each member should has one to two min of report daily; With this you can have more advantage in daily stand up, as how the documentation explain. In case of any bloquers or impediment, in Scrum framework, Scrum Master should take care of Its with the member after daily stand up meeting;

> In order to reach to empiricism benefits using SCRUM or Agile
> techniques, is very important that the dailys meeting occur; no tools
> should replace this ceremony or event.

**Issue Proposal**

Regarding, MT issue,
You can read the below post links, from `Microsoft techcommunity`

1. [Email Notification](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/manage-notifications-in-teams-1cc31834-5fe5-412b-8edb-43fecc78413d#ID0EABAAA=Desktop), explaining how to activate emails notifications
2. [Reminders Notification](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/reminders-in-teams/m-p/300406), Someone else had the same question, regarding configurating reminders in MT
3. [Video with setup reminder explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezkvNhnQkcs)
4. [Post with setup reminder response](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-teams/how-to-set-a-reminder-in-teams/m-p/1151087)

I hope those post help you.